# Return an array of longs from C to Java

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

How would one return an array in C, represented as `long *val`, to Java code?

If it isn't possible to do this this way, how else can I return an Array to Java?

Comment: Why the -1? Please comment and tell me why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start things off, in C you cannot return an array type. In your question, you refer to a "an array in C, represented as long *val". That's not an array. As you should know, `long *` is a *pointer to long*. So, why is this important? Because you're returning a pointer. Not an array. This means that you need to ensure that the memory that pointer points to, will be allocated when the user tries to reference it. A common error in C is to return pointers to memory allocated in automatic storage (i.e. in the stack frame of the function itself.) this is wrong. If you're returning a pointer from a function, that pointer should point to memory that is either: on a stack frame above that function, so we know it's still allocated, such as memory that was allocated in `main()`, static memory that was allocated (such as a global array), or memory allocated on the heap (such as that returned by `malloc()`).

Disclaimer: Heap, stack, and other terms used above have absolutely *nothing* to do with standard C. For practical purposes, I assumed that they exist, but for your purposes, try to get the idea that you shouldn't point to memory that isn't there and then dereference your pointer.

Now, as this relates to JNI and Java, there are some concerns. First off, Java arrays are not laid out in memory the same way arrays are in C. In Java, there is no guarantee that your array's elements will be stored contiguously. I assume there are myriad other problems as well, but I'm not exactly an expert in this field.

So, what's the solution?

Choose an approach.You are either going to have to [copy your array of long into a Java jLongArray as outlined in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354058/copying-c-array-into-java-array-using-jni), or, design an API to access the memory you allocated in C from Java.

However, there is no option of returning a pointer to the array into Java and just accessing it C style. Java does not have pointers, and Java is not C.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it wasn't correct, but just didn't really know enough about C to know what wasn't correct.

Comment: See also the Android JNI Tips doc -- http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#faq_sharing .

Answer (score 1):

You would need more than the log *val, you would also need the count of items in the C array.  Then you just convert it to a array of that size.